# Label's text inside of UICollectionViewCell to vary depending on if statement and array's value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with multiple cells inside of it. Each cell has one label which contains the below data.

What I would like to do is for the labels text that aren't "A" or "B", I would like the value to be an Int value based on the order of the cell.

**Example**

Cells Label text at the moment:

A, A, 3, B, 5, A, B

What I would like:

A, A, 1, B, 2, A, B

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

**Code:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell

        let integerArray = [Int](1...10)
        let sortedCellData = cellData.sorted { $0.key < $1.key}

        if String(Array(sortedCellData)[indexPath.row].value) == "A" {
            cell.valueLabel.text = "A"
        } else if String(Array(sortedCellData)[indexPath.row].value) == "B" {
            cell.valueLabel.text = "B"
        } else {
            cell.valueLabel.text = String(integerArray[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the sort between `A, A, 3, B, 5, A, B` to expected result `A, A, 1, B, 2, A, B`. Could you explicit it? Is it keeps letters, and Int should be replace by "increase" starting at 1? Also, sort it BEFORE loading the `UICollectionView`, not in `cellForItemAt` because you are doing it again and again each time while it could be done for once.

Comment: Hi Larme, yes that is what I mean. So at the moment cell(3) is "3" whereas I would like it it to be "1" and cell(5) is "5" whereas I would like it to be "2". If that makes more sense? Thank you for your help, sorry if I haven't been clear enough!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange sort.

This code should work:

```
let array: [Any] = ["A", "A", 3, "B", 5, "A", "B", "N"]
var index = 0
let sorted = array.compactMap { (element) -> Any? in
    if let asString = element as? String, (asString == "A" || asString == "B") {
        return asString
    } else {
        index = index + 1
        return String(index)
    }
}
print("array: \(array)")
print("sorted: \(sorted)")
```

Output:

```
$>array: ["A", "A", 3, "B", 5, "A", "B", "N"]
$>sorted: ["A", "A", "1", "B", "2", "A", "B", "3"]
```

Logic:
Iterate the elements: `compactMap()`
If it's a String, return it as such (the `if let asString`) if it's equals to "A" or "B"
If it's not, let's increment the "index" and return it as a `String`.

Recommendations: Do it before hand (before loading the `UICollectionView`), and once, not in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` because you are doing the same calculation each time, which is unnecessary, time consuming, and since it's done in main thread, you could see some latency.
Now if you keep `sorted` as an instance var, you just have to do `cell.valueLabel.text = sorted[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Hi Larme, many thanks for the response. Really sorry, but I think you've miss-interpreted my question (my fault completely!). Say my array is ["A", "A", "N", "B", "N", "A", "B"], how can I replace every "N" value with the index value you used? That is what I would like to do, but didn't know how to word the question properly. Thank you!!

Comment: I edited the answer. If it's a `String`, just check for "A" or "B". But is your array only of String? Because if that's the case, then it's even simpler, there is no need to the `if let asString as? String` part.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much!!  (and for the other suggestions!!)

Answer (score 1):

```
Hope this helps, have a nice day :)
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var numCount: Int = 0

var collectionDataIsNumber: [DataObject] = [DataObject(letter: "A", hasNumber: false),
                                            DataObject(letter: "C", hasNumber: true),
                                            DataObject(letter: "B", hasNumber: false),
                                            DataObject(letter: "J", hasNumber: false),
                                            DataObject(letter: "K", hasNumber: true)]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionDataIsNumber.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let data = collectionDataIsNumber[indexPath.row]

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell

    if data.hasNumber{
        numCount += 1
        cell.valueLabel.text = numCount.description
    }else{
        cell.valueLabel.text = data.letter
    }

    return cell
}
}

class DataCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
}

class DataObject{
var letter: String = ""
var hasNumber: Bool = false

init(letter: String, hasNumber: Bool) {
    self.letter = letter
    self.hasNumber = hasNumber
}
}
```

Comment: If you scroll down, then up, you might encounter an issue.

Comment: youre right, thanks for poiting it out,  your  answer was much better anyways, i just tought of sharing another option, which obviously failed XD, but can be fixed, but since there is no need, lets just stick with your answer